# jQuery set ajax return value in form field

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've always used ajax to load() the contents of a DOM element but now I'm trying set a form field value with the result of the following query:

```
$('#form_field').load(base_url+'ajax/get_yearly_fee', {
  'q_value': $(this).val(), 
  'client_id': $("#fee_client_add").val()
});
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.get()` and add a callback to the end of this, see the [`.get` documentation for a full description](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get(base_url+'ajax/get_yearly_fee', {
 'q_value': $(this).val(), 
 'client_id': $("#fee_client_add").val()
}, function(response) {
  $("#form_field").val(response);
});
```

Site note: Substitute `.post` for `.get` if you need to post the data instead.